# Linux kernel - priorities of interrupts

Tags: linux-kernel

If we have two handlers for interrupts in linux kernel:

- hardware interrupt
- hrtimer interrupt

which one has higher priority?

Comment: What makes a hrtimer interrupt any different to a hardware interrupt? o_O

Comment: I think it's platform dependent. For x86, I think there's no priority - first come first served.

Answer (score 0):

I believe by "hardware interrupt" you mean the timer interrupt generated through the APIC.

And, secondly, the hrtimer (High Resolution Timer) subsystem is not actually invoked by a separate interrupt (something like hrtimer interrupt). On the contrary, it is a structured functionality over the same timer handler, meant to provide finer timer granularity.

> At its core, the hrtimer mechanism remains the same. Rather than using the "timer wheel" data structure, hrtimers live on a time-sorted linked list, with the next timer to expire being at the head of the list. A separate red/black tree is also used to enable the insertion and removal of timer events without scanning through the list. But while the core remains the same, just about everything else has changed, at least superficially.

http://lwn.net/Articles/167897/